# How can I only show one responsive menu on mobile devices?

Tags: menus, css, javascript, mobile, responsive

Here's my site:  http://dev.shoeporn.com/

I'm running WP 3.5 and using this plugin:  http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/responsive-select-menu

It is supposed to allow you to select which menus you want to be responsive, but it doesn't seem to work.

I only want the `<div id="header-bar">` menu to be displayed to mobile devices, but currently `<div id="header-nav">` is also shown.

I tried messing around with CSS but I think the "Responsive Select Menu" plugin javascript is overriding it when the page loads.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the "theme_location" parameter for my wp_nav_menu() functions.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/selectively-activate-theme-locations-not-working

Answer (score 0):

check this new plugin. You will love it

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-responsive-menu/